# How can I update an element attribute with a modified value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am working with MachForm and in it when using pricing features it adds this to an li tag:

```
<li id="li_273" data-pricefield="text" data-pricevalue="8.48" >
```

The form also has this field as well:

```
<input type="text" class="element text medium" id="element_273" name="element_273" size="30" value="" />
```

Now what happens is, the form has been converted to an ajax auto complete which is fine and works. But the problem is that the first reference:

```
<li id="li_273" data-pricefield="text" data-pricevalue="8.48" >
```

Isn't going to be the right price for the item selected. So what I need is to be able to re-write that data-pricevalue based on an onclick function. In the autocomplete you are able to execute an onclick javascript command like so:

```
'onclick' => 'alert(\'You clicked on the '.$name.' fruit!\');',
```

Now I have the rest of the javascript that should allow me to take the data-pricevalue from the id (ex: id="li_273") and then multiple it by the value entered into the text box. The ultimate goal is to get data-pricevalue * input text to update the on-screen total value. But I am not sure how to get that data-pricevalue to re-write the proper price.

Comment: do u get the element ..on onclick event.. `console.log($this)` on okclick and check your firebug console..

Comment: The onclick is executed within jquery with: executeCode: true. Then the array as the onclick event allowing for something to happen. I was hoping that command could re-write that li for the correct price.

Comment: when you want to calculate the price?

Comment: The price gets calculated right on screen during the entries. The intention is to select something from the ajax drop down, add a quantity for that item in the next field and the price updates on screen. I can't get it to calculate the right price unless I can re-write that value in the li. SO ajax onclick => re-write li => qty entry => price update